# Golang. О функциях в языке программирования

Tags: golang, процедуры, функции

Дисклеймер:

> **Я не программист.** В большей степени веб-мастер, который сталкивался с кодом по нужде, где требовалось минимум знаний. На уровне объявить переменную и инициализировать ее, значением полученным из GET-параметра. Т.е. уверенно могу сказать, что 100% нуб в языках программирования. Си, Кресты, PHP, javascript – все не про меня. Однако, понимаю предназначение перечисленных, знаю минимально синтаксис оных для идентификации ЯП по исходному коду. Как **первый язык** для изучения программирования выбрал **golang**. И для начала, важным аспектом для себя обозначил механику работы функций (func).

**Утверждение:**

> [Функция](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/7543#sel=20:1,20:55;5:21,5:29), в отличие от процедуры, обязательно возвращает значение.

Согласно процитированному утверждению появились вопросы:

### Ключевые вопросы:

1. В языке golang процедуры являются частным случаем функций?
2. Покажите простой пример функции и процедуры.
3. Какое значение возвращает функция в golang, если ей нечего возвращать?
4. Как на практике убедиться какое значение возвращает функция? 
    Покажите в https://play.golang.org.
5. То, что возвращает функция через return  - есть обязательное значение? (Согласно упомянутому утверждению.)
6. a) Как функция golang понимает откуда её вызвали. b) Как именно вызвали. Как метод или глобально. с) Возможно в ней есть типа аналога js -> `this` , или это все разрешается на этапе компиляции?

---

Comment: Вот не надо по академическим словарям учить программирование. Лучше найди нормальный учебник.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я не пытаюсь учить язык. Это для меня бессмысленно. Я так не запомню. Я легко понял назначение указателей и ссылочных типов, но на функциях просел. На самом деле, это утверждение меня реально сбивает с толку.  Потому-что, понимаю его так:- "Даже пустая функция возвращает, какое-то дефолтное значение. Типа `null` или `что-там` еще." Что касается этого утверждения. Оно есть в википедии. И в многих учебниках. Академ. словарь как пример.

Comment: @bubblebooom, я вам отписал в дополнении к своему ответу.

Comment: @bubblebooom, не верно. Я вам в своем ответе в пункте 5 написал, что в функциях, не возвращающих значения, можно использовать `return` без значения для выхода из функции. Функция не возвращающая значения -- это функция, которая объявлена без указания типа возвращаемого значения.

Comment: @VadimShender - окей. Все понял. Понятия процедуры как таковой в Go - нет. А следовательно вы правы и нужно учитывать 5 пункт. Удаляю мусор из вопроса. + 6 пункт добавил.

Comment: @bubblebooom, еще раз обновил ответ.

Comment: tour.golang.org не? [Программирование на языке G. Марк Саммерфилд](http://karraba.com/programmirovanie-na-yazyike-go.html) не?

Comment: @IvanBlack для начала прочитайте мои вопросы. Далее готур и Саммерфильда

Comment: (1) Если, Вы, господин, начнёте изучать язык, вместо того, чтобы топтаться на псевдо-теоретическом месте, то подобные вопросы просто на просто отпадут. (2) Половина, Ваших "вопросов" исключаются практическим подходом. Слово "процедура" не упоминается ни на tour.golang.org ни у Саммерфильда. (3) Не потрудитесь прочитать правила платформы, на которой задаёте вопросы.

Comment: @Ivan Black, спасибо, кэп.  (4) Мне нечего добавить к ответам  Vadim Shender

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. В языке Go процедур нет, их роль играют функции не возвращающие значений.
2. Вот две функции

   ```
   func addTwo1(a int, b int) int {
       return a + b
   }

   func addTwo2(a int, b int) {
       fmt.Println(a + b)
   }
   ```

   одна возвращает значение, а вторая -- нет.

---

3. Никакого.
4. Что вы подразумеваете под "убедиться на практике"? Можете просто вывести возвращаемое значение на экран, например

   ```
   fmt.Println(addTwo1(1, 2))
   ```

   Для `addTwo2` такое работать не будет, программа не скомпилируется, так как функция `addTwo2` значения не возвращает, а мы пытаемся его использовать для вывода на экран!
5. В Go, если функция не возвращает значение, можно использовать `return` без значения, просто для выхода из функции.

   Пример:

   ```
   func outputPositiveNumber(n int) {
       if (n < 0)
           return  // выходим из функции, не возвращая значение

       // этот код выполнится, только если n >= 0
       fmt.Printf("n = %d\n", n)
   }
   ```

---

**Обновление**

По вашим комментариям: много в каких языках программирования сделано более "академически", ближе к *математическому* смыслу понятия *функции*. Например в том же функциональном OCaml любая функция возвращает значение. Если нам нечего возвращать, функция возвращает специальный тип `unit`, который имеет единственное значение `()` -- ничего.

Или взять язык типа Pascal, там явно выделено понятие процедуры, когда возвращать нечего.
о
В языке же C (и унаследованных от него Java, Go и т.д.) решили (для простоты, наверное) ограничиться лишь понятием функции, которой, среди прочего, позволено значений не возвращать, о чем явно указывается при объявлении этих самых функций. *Функции, не возвращающие ничего*, -- всего лишь выбранный способ решения вопроса о том, как реализуются сущности, позволяющие инкапсулировать код, но не возвращающие значений, которые вызываются лишь ради их побочных эффектов (*процедуры)*. Можете в случае Go считать, что функции, не возвращающие ничего, на самом деле являются процедурами, если вам так удобнее (в математическом смысле они функциями, конечно же, не являются). Просто, продолжая эту мысль, "процедуры" в Go для простоты и единообразия объявляютcя с помощью того же синтаксиса, что и обычные функции, лишь без указания возвращаемого значения.

---

**Обновление**

6.

- а) Никак. Функции не нужно знать, откуда ее вызвали. Ее дело взять переданные параметры, выполнить свой код, вернуть, если нужно, значение. Кто и откуда функцию вызвал, для нее не имеет никакого значения.
- b) Методы и функции различаются на этапе компиляции. Метод нельзя вызывать как функцию, а функцию -- вызывать как метод.
- c) Как уже понятно, да, все это решается на этапе компиляции.

Comment: Простите, Вадим. Мозги кипят :)

Comment: Пункт (5). `return` без операнда, не возвращает значение только если функция не возвращает значение, а в Вашем примере `return` вернёт ноль. Вот [пример](http://play.golang.org/p/3HJLlLWv__). Это тонкость языка. Эквивалент [примера](http://play.golang.org/p/eiSriOgh1I) для ясности. А вот [этот](http://play.golang.org/p/CvEBkAI-rx) уже не скомпилируется и [этот](http://play.golang.org/p/hQj8RQH4o9) тоже. Впрочем, уверен, Вы про это знаете. Просто уточняю.

Comment: @IvanBlack, в моем примере функция как раз-таки и не возвращает значения, посмотрите внимательнее, поэтому и `return` никаких значений не возвращает тоже. Ошибка в примере, к слову, все равно есть. В отличие от C/C++/C#/Java фигурные скобки для выделеня блоков кода в конструкциях `if`, `for` и т.д. в Go обязательны, а я их поставить забыл. Но, думаю, основную мысль донести все равно удалось.

Comment: @VadimShender, да. Я тупанул. Проглядел и решил, что `(n int)` это возвращаемое значение. Вроде `func outputPositiveNumber() (n int) {..}`

Comment: @IvanBlack, да, я так и подумал по вашему примеру :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Да.
2. См. ссылку в конце.
3. Она ничего не возвращает. Попытка использовать её "возвращаемое значение" ведёт к ошибке компиляции.
4. Не понятно, о чём вы. Значение, возвращаемое функцией, можно присвоить переменной, или передать в другую, или делать всё что угодно.
5. Опять же, что значит "обязательное"? У функций с именованными возвратными значениями, эти значения по умолчанию нулевые для данного типа.

https://play.golang.org/p/pUqh4fpL4X

Comment: На самом деле, это утверждение меня реально сбивает с толку. Потому-что, понимаю его так:- "Даже пустая функция возвращает, какое-то дефолтное значение. Типа `null` или `что-там` еще. _Я не правильно интерпретирую данное утверждение?_ :)

Comment: это был ответ, о чём я.